# Two Mongoose schema reference each other when iserting data via POST

Tags: node.js, post, mongoose

I'm very new to Mongoose and Node.js I have 2 schema. One is client and the other is project. A user can make a new project (give it a project name) and a user can create a new client (give it a client name) but the user has the option to add a client to a project and can add a project to a client.

What I want to do is, when you do a POST request, you can enter a project name and a client name. The client name should then go into the client schema and project into project schema but I'm not sure how one schema references the other.

This is my Client schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Project = require('./project_models');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
//
 var clientSchema = Schema({
 project: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Project' },
 client: String
 });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Client', clientSchema);
```

The second one is project

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Client = require('./client_models');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
//
var projectSchema = Schema({
  client: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Client' },
  project: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Project', projectSchema);
```

This is my post function (It works if I insert just a project title on it's own, same with client)

```
app.post('/project', function(req, res, next) {
var newProject = new Project(req.body);
newProject.save(function(err, project) {
if (err) { return next(err); }
return res.json(project);
});
```

On Postman when carrying out a POST request, this is what I enter for
localhost3000:/project

```
{
 "client":"john",
 "project":"db"
}
```

I get this error

> "message": "Cast to ObjectID failed for value \"john\" at path \"client\"",

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to previously create the project with name "db" then save it and add it to your user and then save your user, and you're not really supposed to make relation in both model.

Or the same but with the project as "main model" depends on your use of it

Comment: Thanks. When I create a project with name db, it will go into my project collection in Mongodb. How do I add it to the user though?

Comment: when you save it you get a promise with the doc saved, in this doc you have a field _id it's the value you have to give to your "project" field in your user Edit : not sure if it returns a promise but if it doesn't you can give a callback to save